# Como ler um arquivo txt de apenas uma linha em VBA?

Tags: vba

Gostaria de ler um arquivo txt através do VBA.

Todos os códigos que encontrei na internet fazem um loop no arquivo(para pegar todas as linhas suponho eu), mas eu queria pegar apenas a primeira linha de forma mais simples e colocar numa variável.

Eis meu código atual, que pega o texto porém não estou achando legal:

```
Dim conexao As String

Dim ReadData As String

Open "C:\Sistema\Conexao.txt" For Input As #1

Do Until EOF(1)
   Line Input #1, ReadData
   conexao = ReadData
If Not Left(ReadData, 1) = "*" Then
End If

Loop

Close #1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O melhor que pude chegar foi da seguinte maneira:

```
Sub Buscar_Primeira_Linha()

Dim LINHA As Integer

    ' Configura o número da linha que deseja
    LINHA = 1 ' Primeira Linha, por exemplo

    Ler_Arquivo "C:\Arquivo.txt", LINHA

End Sub
```

Creio que assim funcione... segue a função `Ler_Arquivo`:

```
Function Ler_Arquivo(ByRef ARQUIVO As String, _
                 Optional ByRef LINHA As Integer) As String

Dim COUNT As Integer

    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(ARQUIVO)

        If LINHA < 1 Then LINHA = 1
        COUNT = 1

        Do While Not .AtEndOfStream

            If COUNT = LINHA Then
                Ler_Arquivo = .ReadLine
                Exit Do
            Else
                .SkipLine
            End If
            COUNT = COUNT + 1
        Loop
       .Close
    End With

End Function
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

Para lêr apenas a primeira linha, não utilize o ciclo `Do`.

Contudo, parece-me que este código faz alguma validação para procurar a primeira linha começada (ou não) por `"*"`. E sendo este o caso, o ciclo é necessário.

Answer (score -1):

Function LerArquivo()

NomeArquivo = "C:\Dados\meuarquivo.txt"

Open NomeArquivo For Input As #1

```
LerAte = 2

Do While Not EOF(1)

    If Linha < LerAte Then Line Input #1, Texto: Linha = Linha + 1
    
    If Linha >= LerAte Then Exit Do
    
Loop
```

Close #1

End Function